# How can I give my test client the client secret without hardcoding it (in C#)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, unit-testing, xunit

So I am trying to run some tests on my project and one issue that I am having is that any method that requires me to create a test client returns the following error:

```
System.Argument.NullException : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'clientSecret')
```

For example, I have to create a test client for a certain test in XUnit:

```
var client = CreateHttpClient();
```

and the CreateHttpClient() looks something like this:

```
        private HttpClient CreateHttpClient(bool authenticated = true)
        {
            var client = _factory.CreateClient();

            if (authenticated)
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(AuthenticationConstants.TestScheme);
            }

            return client;
        }
```

When I run it the client gets created but it seems the client has no client secret. Within our secrets.json file, there is a client secret that is written like this:

```
    "Swagger": {
      "ClientSecret": "xxxxxxxxx__xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx"
    }
```

How can I give my test client a client secret so that this error does not occur?

Comment: So your xunit project has a secrets.json?

Comment: A HTTP request can have many different HTTP headers.  One of these headers is Authentication.  Looks like you need to send a custom http header "ClientSecret".

Comment: The xunit project does not but the overall C#/asp.net project does. In order to run the app and access the Swagger UI, you need to have the correct clientSecret

Comment: Is this a unit test or an integration test?

Comment: This is for a fact unit test

Comment: If this is a unit test, you should just be able to mock your dependencies and then create a callback to read the reader to make sure the correct secret was passed